# Android : Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getTracker

Tags: android, android-build

I have an app that makes use of the Google Analytics library. I recently moved the code into a new workspace and the app has stopped working. The code builds OK but when it runs it halts with the following error.

```
06-12 23:11:14.117: I/dalvikvm(31080): Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getTracker, referenced from method com.apps4care.v2conf.utils.analytics.raiseEvent
06-12 23:11:14.117: W/dalvikvm(31080): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7179: Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;.getTracker ()Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/Tracker;
06-12 23:11:14.117: D/dalvikvm(31080): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0021
06-12 23:11:14.117: I/dalvikvm(31080): Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getInstance, referenced from method com.apps4care.v2conf.utils.analytics.start
06-12 23:11:14.117: W/dalvikvm(31080): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7178: Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;.getInstance ()Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;
06-12 23:11:14.117: D/dalvikvm(31080): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
06-12 23:11:14.117: I/dalvikvm(31080): Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getInstance, referenced from method com.apps4care.v2conf.utils.analytics.stop
06-12 23:11:14.117: W/dalvikvm(31080): VFY: unable to resolve static method 7178: Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;.getInstance ()Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;
```

The analytics JAR is in my "libs" folder and I can see it listed in the "Libraries" tab on the Java Build Path within Properties.

Any clues how I can fix this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're in Eclipse.

Right click on your project, select Properties.

Under Java Build Path, click on Order & Export tab.

Check Android Private Libraries and click OK.

Comment: Yes I'm on Eclipse - will check later today to see if this helps