# Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getInstance

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I'm trying to integrate Google Analitics in android, but I have some doubts and problems.

1.- Using EasyTracker Jar is needed libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar?

2.- I followed this guide

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/?hl=es#analytics-xml

I have Easytracker.jar in my build but it throws this error.

This is the easytracker i did downloaded ->

http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/detail?name=EasyTrackerAndroid_1.0.zip&can=2&q=

```
10-26 17:44:45.411: I/dalvikvm(2972): Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getInstance, referenced from method com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.Splash.onStart
10-26 17:44:45.411: W/dalvikvm(2972): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3570: Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;
10-26 17:44:45.421: D/dalvikvm(2972): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
10-26 17:44:45.421: I/dalvikvm(2972): Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getInstance, referenced from method com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.Splash.onStop
10-26 17:44:45.421: W/dalvikvm(2972): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3570: Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/EasyTracker;
10-26 17:44:45.421: D/dalvikvm(2972): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
10-26 17:44:45.431: I/BugSenseHandler(2972): Registering default exceptions handler
10-26 17:44:45.526: D/dalvikvm(2972): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 132K, 4% free 13772K/14211K, paused 29ms
10-26 17:44:45.531: I/dalvikvm-heap(2972): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.155MB for 1536016-byte allocation
10-26 17:44:45.566: D/dalvikvm(2972): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 15271K/15751K, paused 14ms
```

Comment: Hi david, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076446/android-could-not-find-method-com-google-analytics-tracking-android-easytracke?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but I tried and don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Eclipse, right click on your project, select Properties.
2. Under Java Build Path, click on Order & Export tab. Check Android Private
   Libraries and click OK.
3. Clean the project and rebuild it.
   It should work now.