# Android EasyTracker class do not contain method getTracker()

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics-api, easytracker

I am using EasyTracker in my `PreferenceActivity`

```
@Override
public void onStart ()
{
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop ()
{
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
}
```

But when I trying to call `getTracker()` method in `EasyTracker` class it is not there.

[image]

And this [Android : Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getTracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076446/android-could-not-find-method-com-google-analytics-tracking-android-easytracke) do not help.

Comment: Can you please provide the name of jar that you are using?

Comment: libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar

Comment: I am using "libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar"  in my app and its working fine for me and showing getTracker() method.

Comment: 100% problem is related jar.please clean project and re run application.

Comment: right click in your jar file->Build path->add to Build path.. try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar :

```
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;

    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Google Analytics Start Activity
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
    EasyTracker.getTracker();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Google Analytics Stop Activity
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar Version 3.x, where they change the API, so now the getIntance() method requires a Context object as an input. If you are using this inside an Activity just pass MyActivityName.this as a value.

For more information, see the Google Analytics SDK for Android: Migrating to v3:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration