# Android Google Analytics

Tags: java, android

I have used this documentation to implement google analytics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods

But it is giving the error mentioned below.

```
09-20 04:13:56.171: E/Trace(6513): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-20 04:13:56.241: W/dalvikvm(6513): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5881: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics;
09-20 04:13:56.241: E/dalvikvm(6513): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker', referenced from method com.myCompany.news.myCompanyApplication.getTracker
09-20 04:13:56.251: W/dalvikvm(6513): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 884 (Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker;) in Lcom/myCompany/news/myCompanyApplication;
```

I have tried this but it does not work [Android : Could not find method com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getTracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076446/android-could-not-find-method-com-google-analytics-tracking-android-easytracke?lq=1)

Comment: Have you included the Play Services library as a dependency in your application? Are you using proguard when compiling your app?

Comment: yes, I have included library. I do not think I am using proguard, not sure though, can you please let me know where to check?

Comment: I have reinstalled eclipse, ADT; It is working now :) don't have a clue why it was having issues.

Comment: Same mysterious problem here. :( Now, I try to reinstall ADT.

Comment: Still if you are having the problem, you can see my post how to code the GA. You must include the google play updated lib.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964859/google-analytics-networkonmainthreadexception-on-send-in-asynctask/27997021#27997021